# Mongoose post save hook from subdocument executed multiple times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hook

I have a subdocument defined in a parent document array, just like the example at:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html.

Well, I add a post save hook at the subdocument schema, because I need to know when something it's saved in that field. Something like this:

```
    var ChildSchema = new Schema({
      childName: String
    });

    var ParentSchema = new Schema({
      children: [ChildSchema]
    });

    ChildSchema
    .post("save", function(doc) {
       console.log(doc);
     });
```

When a new children it's addedd (or updated an existing one) and then the parent saved, the post save hook it's executed two times. But if I create the hook just for the parent, then executes just once.

I don't know why it's that. I just guessing that the hook it's executed by the parent and then by the children, because with the child schema hook created also creates a hook to parent schema..This is just guessing because I don't know what's going on.

Hope you can help me.

Thx.

> -----------    I redefine the question       -----------------

I have a document defined at mongoose model. The document has 3 child subdocs.

Well, I need to insert documents, sometimes without the subdocs. Later I need to push/insert or update subdocs.
When I save a subdoc I need to get just the one (just the subdoc) which has been inserted or updated to send to the client side with socket.io and I can't do that so far.

Comment: Don't get it. ChildSchema is "embedded" so why would you want a "post save" hook there? Only the parent ever gets saved. The child data is a part of that.

Comment: I create a Parent object and saved it. I need to add and update children later. Finally I want to get just the subdoc that was changed to send by socket.io. I took this solution to my problem. How could I in another way know the subdoc that was changed or added?

Comment: Second person to tell within 5 minutes. When asking questions of your peers, don't ask how to do what you think is a solution, but present the problem you have to solve and the desired outcome. That way we see the problem just as you have, but may come to a different solution to get to the result. Edit your question to explain your use case. What you think is the way to solve it is not the way to solve it.